# How to automatically go to the next track when the one is currently playing ends?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm quite new to swift and I want to implement a piece of code that helps me reach the next song when the one that is currently playing ends.
I tried to copy the code inside my "@IBAction func nextAction" (which works fine):

```
@IBAction func nextAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.nextTrack()
}

func nextTrack() {

        if trackId == 0 || trackId < 4 {
            if shuffle.on {
                trackId = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(library.count)))
            }else {
                trackId += 1
            }

            if let coverImage = library[trackId]["coverImage"]{
                coverImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(coverImage).jpg")
            }

            songTitleLabel.text = library[trackId]["title"]
            artistLabel.text = library[trackId]["artist"]

            audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
            progressView.progress = 0

            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(trackId)", ofType: "mp3")

            if let path = path {
                let mp3URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

                do {
                    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3URL)
                    audioPlayer.play()

                    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(PlayerViewController.updateProgressView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                    progressView.setProgress(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime/audioPlayer.duration), animated: false)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }

}
```

And tried to put it inside an if condition like this (inside the viewDidLoad):

```
if audioPlayer.currentTime >= audioPlayer.duration {
        self.nextTrack()
    }
```

I don't have any errors but at runtime this method isn't working and the song ends without playing the next one.

To make the situation more clear here's my controller:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var coverImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var songTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var artistLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var shuffle: UISwitch!

    var trackId: Int = 0
    var library = MusicLibrary().library
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if let coverImage = library[trackId]["coverImage"]{
            coverImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(coverImage).jpg")
        }

        songTitleLabel.text = library[trackId]["title"]
        artistLabel.text = library[trackId]["artist"]

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(trackId)", ofType: "mp3")

        if let path = path {
            let mp3URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3URL)
                audioPlayer.play()

                NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(PlayerViewController.updateProgressView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                progressView.setProgress(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime/audioPlayer.duration), animated: false)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }

    func updateProgressView(){

        if audioPlayer.playing {

            progressView.setProgress(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime/audioPlayer.duration), animated: true)
        }

    }


    @IBAction func playAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        if !audioPlayer.playing {
            audioPlayer.play()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func stopAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
        progressView.progress = 0
    }


    @IBAction func pauseAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        audioPlayer.pause()
    }

    @IBAction func fastForwardAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        var time: NSTimeInterval = audioPlayer.currentTime
        time += 5.0

        if time > audioPlayer.duration {
            stopAction(self)
        }else {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = time
        }

    }

    @IBAction func rewindAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        var time: NSTimeInterval = audioPlayer.currentTime
        time -= 5.0

        if time < 0 {
            stopAction(self)
        }else {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = time
        }
    }

    @IBAction func previousAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        if trackId != 0 || trackId > 0 {
            if shuffle.on {
                trackId = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(library.count)))
            }else {
                trackId -= 1
            }

            if let coverImage = library[trackId]["coverImage"]{
                coverImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(coverImage).jpg")
            }

            songTitleLabel.text = library[trackId]["title"]
            artistLabel.text = library[trackId]["artist"]

            audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
            progressView.progress = 0

            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(trackId)", ofType: "mp3")

            if let path = path {
                let mp3URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

                do {
                    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3URL)
                    audioPlayer.play()

                    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(PlayerViewController.updateProgressView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                    progressView.setProgress(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime/audioPlayer.duration), animated: false)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }




    }

    @IBAction func swipeDownAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.close()
    }

    @IBAction func closeAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.close()
    }

    @IBAction func nextAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.nextTrack()
    }

    func close() {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    func nextTrack() {

        if trackId == 0 || trackId < 4 {
            if shuffle.on {
                trackId = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(library.count)))
            }else {
                trackId += 1
            }

            if let coverImage = library[trackId]["coverImage"]{
                coverImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(coverImage).jpg")
            }

            songTitleLabel.text = library[trackId]["title"]
            artistLabel.text = library[trackId]["artist"]

            audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
            progressView.progress = 0

            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(trackId)", ofType: "mp3")

            if let path = path {
                let mp3URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

                do {
                    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3URL)
                    audioPlayer.play()

                    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(PlayerViewController.updateProgressView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                    progressView.setProgress(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime/audioPlayer.duration), animated: false)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

All the code is written in Xcode 7.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `AVAudioPlayer` delegate method `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool)` which is called when the audio player finishes playing a sound.

1. Make your `PlayerViewController` confirm to `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` protocol like this:

   ```
   class PlayerViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
   ```
2. Make sure to set `self` as the delegate of the audioPlayer you create, to do that in your `viewDidLoad`,`previousAction` and `nextTrack` method you need to add

   ```
   audioPlayer.delegate = self
   ```

   after this line:

   ```
   audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3URL)
   ```
3. Now you can use the delegate method to know when the audio is finished playing and go to the next track, just add this inside your class:

   ```
   func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
       if flag {
           self.nextTrack()
       } else {
           // did not finish successfully
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you've dedicated to me! It works perfectly.